# Java: file cannot be resolved

Tags: java

the following code is returning the following error message:

```
package demo3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            openFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("File not found: " + file.toString());
    }
}

public static void openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
}

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
file cannot be resolved

at demo3.App.main(App.java:13)
```

I'm not sure whether this is because the file is in a different class to the try catch loop or if it's caused by something else. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: file is only available inside the method where you declared it.

Comment: *"this is because the file is in a different class"* different _method_, but yes, this is the problem.

Comment: `file.toString()` cannot be resolved to a type, because it's not declared within the context of the class or method you are trying to use it

Comment: Actually it is unclear what are you asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling the FileNotFound exception in your main method, handle it in your `openFile()` method.

Right now you're trying to access the `file` method where the variable has not been defined. The `file` variable has only been defined in the `openFile()` method.

You can also define it above your main method. If you do that, every method in your class will have access to it.

Either solution will solve your problem. Choose the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way to define the file variable in both methods?

Comment: Yes, you can define it above your main method. If you do that, every method in your class will have access to it.